# Custom Style For AutoComplete ComboBox Popup

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, wpf-style

I implemented a WPF Application which is responsible for web scraping. So the application contains a Combo Box to select Screens, and I can scrape elements under each Screen based on the selection. Now I am planning to change the Combo Box to Auto Complete(Searchable Combo Box). The good part is I implemented it inside my normal Combo Box and it is working and the bad part is I got a requirement to change the UI something similar to the image I attached. Can someone more into WPF figure out can it possible or not or is there any specific style we can achieve somewhat similar to that. Attaching the image

[image]

Comment: You can do this by editing the style

Comment: @Vimal CK But I am not sure in what way I need to edit, if someone did it before or anyone knew how to do then it will be better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom style. First I would suggest you experiment with the item template of ComboBox itself.

```
<ComboBox>
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                   <YourAutoComplete />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Then for your `AutoComplete` control, you can use already created styles -
https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro
https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit